# How to find which numpy array contains the maximum value on an element by element basis?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Given a list of numpy arrays, each with the same dimensions, how can I find which array contains the maximum value on an element-by-element basis?

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
def find_index_where_max_occurs(my_list):
    # d = ...  something goes here ...
    return d

a=np.array([1,1,3,1])
b=np.array([3,1,1,1])
c=np.array([1,3,1,1])

my_list=[a,b,c]

array_of_indices_where_max_occurs = find_index_where_max_occurs(my_list)

# This is what I want:
# >>> print array_of_indices_where_max_occurs
# array([1,2,0,0])
# i.e. for the first element, the maximum value occurs in array b which is at index 1 in my_list.
```

Any help would be much appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option if you want an array:

```
>>> np.array((a, b, c)).argmax(axis=0)
array([1, 2, 0, 0])
```

So:

```
def f(my_list):
    return np.array(my_list).argmax(axis=0)
```

This works with multidimensional arrays, too.

Comment: Thanks - this looks good. I think I'll mark this as my preferred answer. I know this wasn't part of my original question, but could this be extended to work with 2d numpy arrays?

Comment: @PeteW With the result being another 2d array? or a 1d array?

Comment: @PeteW `np.dstack((a,b,c)).argmax(axis=2)`

Comment: @PeteW I think the edited version works with both 1D and 2D arrays

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, apparently the stacking was overkill :)

Comment: @askewchan Thinking properly in `numpy` terms is an art I have yet to master :)

Comment: @LevLevitsky Yes, but the stacking will be much faster. `timeit np.dstack((a,b,c)).argmax(2): 31 us per loop`
`timeit np.asarray((a,b,c)).argmax(0): 93.7 us per loop`

Comment: @PeteW I have a generalized version of the stack as another answer now.  It is about five times faster than this answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of it, I realised that @Lev's original answer was faster than his generalized edit, so this is the generalized stacking version which is much faster than the `np.asarray` version, but it is not very elegant.

```
np.concatenate((a[None,...], b[None,...], c[None,...]), axis=0).argmax(0)
```

That is:

```
def bystack(arrs):
    return np.concatenate([arr[None,...] for arr in arrs], axis=0).argmax(0)
```

Some explanation:

I've added a new axis to each array: `arr[None,...]` is equivalent to `arr[np.newaxis,...]` which is the same as `arr[np.newaxis,:,:,:]` where the `...` expands to be the appropriate number dimensions.  The reason for this is because `np.concatenate` will then stack along the new dimension, which is `0` since the `None` is at the front.

So, for example:

```
In [286]: a
Out[286]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])

In [287]: b
Out[287]: 
array([[10, 11],
       [12, 13]])

In [288]: np.concatenate((a[None,...],b[None,...]),axis=0)
Out[288]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],

       [[10, 11],
        [12, 13]]])
```

In case it helps to understand, this would work too:

```
np.concatenate((a[...,None], b[...,None], c[...,None]), axis=a.ndim).argmax(a.ndim)
```

where the new axis is now added at the end, so we must stack and maximize along that last axis, which will be `a.ndim`.  For `a`, `b`, and `c` being 2d, we could do this:

```
np.concatenate((a[:,:,None], b[:,:,None], c[:,:,None]), axis=2).argmax(2)
```

Which is equivalent to the `dstack` I mentioned in my comment above (`dstack` adds a third axis to stack along if it doesn't exist in the arrays).

To test:

```
N = 10
M = 2

a = np.random.random((N,)*M)
b = np.random.random((N,)*M)
c = np.random.random((N,)*M)

def bystack(arrs):
    return np.concatenate([arr[None,...] for arr in arrs], axis=0).argmax(0)

def byarray(arrs):
    return np.array(arrs).argmax(axis=0)

def byasarray(arrs):
    return np.asarray(arrs).argmax(axis=0)

def bylist(arrs):
    assert arrs[0].ndim == 1, "ndim must be 1"
    return [np.argmax(x) for x in zip(*arrs)]



In [240]: timeit bystack((a,b,c))
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.3 us per loop

In [241]: timeit byarray((a,b,c))
10000 loops, best of 3: 89.7 us per loop

In [242]: timeit byasarray((a,b,c))
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.0 us per loop

In [259]: timeit bylist((a,b,c))
1000 loops, best of 3: 267 us per loop
```

Comment: Very nice. I need to wrap my head around those `None` axes and ellipses... once

Comment: @LevLevitsky `None` here does the same as `np.newaxis`, which increases `ndim`, adding a length-` dimension in the spot where the `np.newaxis` is.  I put it at the beginning, so that shape goes from `(n,m)` to `(1,n,m)` then stacked and maxed along that axis. I could have put it at the end and stacked/maxed over `axis=a.ndim` isntead of `axis=0`.  Without the extra axis, `np.concatenate` won't increase the `ndim` so one will be lost in the maxing.

Answer (score 1):

```
[np.argmax(x) for x in zip(*my_list)]
```

Well, this is just a list, but you know how to make it an array if you want.  :)

To explain what this does: `zip(*my_list)` is equivalent to `zip(a,b,c)`, which gives you a generator to loop over.  Each step in the loop gives you a tuple like `(a[i], b[i], c[i])`, where `i` is the step in the loop.  Then, `np.argmax` gives you the index of that tuple for the element with the largest value.